# Portlet is deployed alright, but shows error message temporarily unavailable. Errors in the log say jsp is not available to server

Tags: jsp, liferay, tomcat7

I'm hoping someone can point something about this problem. I deployed two portlets from the same Liferay project, one in the Control Panel and another in the more general add more category.

But upon viewing them on the portal, the one that can be added to the pages shows that portlet is temporarily unavailable, and the other shows in Control Panel, but shows nothing but the title.

I looked at the log in liferay-(today's date).log and the errors show that the server can't find the jsp's. Errors are like so:

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-5][PortletRequestDispatcherImpl:115]  javax.servlet.ServletException: Archivo JSP &quot;/registros/view.jsp&quot; no encontrado
javax.servlet.ServletException: Archivo JSP &quot;/registros/view.jsp&quot; no      encontrado
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:412)
etc... etc...
```

for the portlet in the add more category, and for the portlet in control panel:

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-3][MVCPortlet:366] null is not a valid include
15:54:51,434 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-3][ComboServlet:92]   javax.servlet.ServletException: Resource /css/EContinuaAdmin.css does not exist in caja-    virtual-portlet
javax.servlet.ServletException: Resource /css/EContinuaAdmin.css does not exist in  caja-virtual-portlet
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ComboServlet.getResourceURL(ComboServlet.java:364)

etc... etc...

ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-3][status_jsp:769] javax.servlet.ServletException: Resource     /js/EContinuaAdmin.js does not exist in caja-virtual-portlet
javax.servlet.ServletException: Resource /js/EContinuaAdmin.js does not exist in caja-    virtual-portlet
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ComboServlet.getResourceURL(ComboServlet.java:364)

etc... etc...
```

And also for this last portlet:

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-3][MVCPortlet:366] null is not a valid include
15:55:43,057 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-3][code_jsp:128] {code="404", msg="/caja-    virtual-portleticon.png", uri=/caja-virtual-portleticon.png}
15:57:48,762 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-1][code_jsp:128] {code="404", msg="/caja-    virtual-portleticon.png", uri=/caja-virtual-portleticon.png}
15:57:50,002 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-3][code_jsp:128] {code="404", msg="/caja- virtual-portleticon.png", uri=/caja-virtual-portleticon.png}
15:58:12,180 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-7][MVCPortlet:366] null is not a valid include
15:58:12,934 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-7][ComboServlet:92]    javax.servlet.ServletException: Resource /css/EContinuaAdmin.css does not exist in caja-    virtual-portlet
javax.servlet.ServletException: Resource /css/EContinuaAdmin.css does not exist in     caja-virtual-portlet
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ComboServlet.getResourceURL(ComboServlet.java:364)

etc... etc...
```

I can understand most of the errors in the second case I've shown, because there's effectively no such js or css files in the project, but I don't understand why it's not finding the jsp's. 
I'll show my portlet.xml so it is clear:

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>caja-virtual</portlet-name>
        <display-name>Caja Virtual</display-name>
        <portlet-class>com.cide.cajaVirtual.EContinua.portlet.CajaVirtualPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>view-template</name>
            <value>/registros/view.jsp</value>
        </init-param>
```

There are two folders where I have jsp's: admin and registros, so why is this happening. And also, what to do about the other errors, I'm not sure. Should I drop simply an EContinuaAdmin.css and a EContinuaAdmin.js in the js and css folders? Finally, why is the project asking for those files isn't clear to me, I only have a main.css and a main.js in those folders which Eclipse creates automatically for the liferay plugin project.

Aditionally (and I'm sorry if this looks like it should be another question, it's just that I want to show all the errors because the log is too cryptic to me and I wanna discard options) I see this last two errors in the log which I don't know why happen:

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-2][DefaultTransactionExecutor:93] Application exception     overridden by commit exception
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object     of class [com.liferay.portal.model.impl.PortalPreferencesImpl] with identifier [11178]:     optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row     was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect):     [com.liferay.portal.model.impl.PortalPreferencesImpl#11178]

etc... etc...

ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-2][PortalPreferencesImpl:192]     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of     class [com.liferay.portal.model.impl.PortalPreferencesImpl] with identifier [11178]:     optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row     was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect):     [com.liferay.portal.model.impl.PortalPreferencesImpl#11178]
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object     of class [com.liferay.portal.model.impl.PortalPreferencesImpl] with identifier [11178]:     optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row     was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect):     [com.liferay.portal.model.impl.PortalPreferencesImpl#11178]
at
etc... etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

- check if your deployed plugin actually has `/registros/view.jsp` (for tomcat it should be in `webapps/caja-virtual-portlet/registros/view.jsp`). If not, make sure that your project has it in `docroot/registros/view.jsp`
- You might also want to check your `liferay-portlet.xml` for paths that you give - e.g. for css, js and the icon. The URL I see for your icon shows a missing "/" - which you should add to the icon entry in `liferay-portlet.xml`
- You might want to investigate where the spaces in `caja-    virtual-portleticon.png` in your log come from - seems like a line-break after formatting an xml file.

If that doesn't help, try to check if deployment worked like it should: E.g. if you find all the resources that you expect in your WAR file - they might be ending up in directories where Ant (or whatever you build with) doesn't expect them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I ended up setting a separate html folder in docroot and then calling `docroot/html/registros/view.jsp` Right now I no longer remember how I had it setup, but it seemed like I had the whole folder structure wrong. It worked afterwards.